# Watch component's $el properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The initial problem was to compute data each time the component's width changes.

To do so, my first idea was to watch the component's **$el** props with the following, but the function is never called.

```
watch: {
  '$el.offsetWidth': (value) => {
    console.log('$el.offsetWidth changed', value);
    this.success = true;
    this.getOffsetWidth();
  },
},
```

Am I doing anything wrong or Is it impossible to watch those properties ?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasFerro/bf33b0xk/)'s the JSFiddle where I've tried to implement the solution.

Note : Please be aware that *watch the window's resize event isn't a solution* since the component can be resized inside the application.

Comment: That's not how Vue's reactivity works.  I suggest you review [Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) to understand Vue's reactivity implementation.  You'll find that what you probably want is a javascript library to handle resize detection -- and integrate it with Vue (possibly as a plugin).

Comment: You'll want a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver on the elements in question setup in mounted

Comment: @PatrickSteele : Thanks for the precision, I was indeed misunderstanding the reactivity.

Comment: @robertotomás : I'll try to implement that solution on my JSFiddle, thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: @robertotomás The MutationObserver API doesn't seems to be able to detect element resizing, have you tried it ? (example : https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasFerro/bf33b0xk/2/ )

Comment: I'm sorry, you re right. there are special ResizeObservers for that...but that may not be generic enough/polyfillable for your use

Comment: The ResizeObserver API seems promising but it's not yet supported, according to *Can I Use* : https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver